# MS Exchange Server 2003: any good scripting tutorial?

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2003

I need to write a script for MS Exchange Server 2003 that will analyze incoming emails and put some of them into a specific mailbox. Of course it's a lot of information about Exchange Server scripting at MSDN, but amount of information there is very huge. Is it some simple tutorials available that will describe how to install a simple script on MS Exchange Server that will analyze incoming emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way to accomplish what you want in exchange 2003 is to write an smtp event sink.  Here is an overview.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csmanagedeventsinkshooks.aspx

Unfortunately, event sinks can be prone to have very poor performance characteristics and are generally discouraged.  However, I believe that is the way to accomplish what you want to do.

If you decide to go down this path, here are a couple of references for you:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894286 and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998610.aspx

Comment: Thanks, i have sucessfully solved the task using event sink in vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

Try these? (the first one is for exchange 07)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exchange/Exchange2007EWS-Part1.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Exchange_2003_with_WebDav.aspx